# How to format a System Active Primary Partition?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, formatting

I have two internal HDD. HDD 1 and HDD 2.
In, HDD 1 there are 5 volumes - C,D,E,F,G
In, HDD 2 there are 5 volumes - H,I,J,K,L

Now, I had my previous OS (Windows 8) in "C" in HDD 1. Then i installed Windows 8.1 in "H" in HDD 2. When computer starts its asks me what OS i want to use. Now i want to format "C" (In which previous OS was installed) but Windows does not let me do that. It's saying "Windows can not format the system partition on this disk" and it is marked as "System,Active,Primary partition". Now experts is there any solution you can give me so that i can format "C"?  I dont want to reinstall the windows.

Comment: Mark another drive as System, Active, and Primary? You can do this with Disk Management.

Comment: I can mark the "H" (In which the new OS is installed) as Active which i did. But how to mark it as System? And by the way, even i mark "H" as Active "C" is still Active System and Primary

Answer (score 1):

That partition is the first partition of the first hard disk and contains the bootloader. Even though you installed Windows in another partition, it was used by Windows to store boot data (just like the System Reserved partition).

Of course, you can boot a live Linux USB or CD with GParted and format the drive, but this will make your Windows non bootable.

Another thing I'm thinking of is to temporarily remove the first HDD from your computer. Then if Windows will not boot insert the Windows DVD and boot from it. Choose the repair option when prompted to **Install Now**. Open a command line and run `bootsect /fixboot` and `bootsect /fixmbr`. Run these commands a few times and change the order until you get no errors. When you reinsert the HDD be sure it is not the first boot device in BIOS!

Comment: What do you mean by becoming the windows unbootable? I wont be able to install any other os again?

Comment: And by removing the first HDD means to plug out the cable? And i did not installed with a CD, I just copied the whole thing inside the CD in my computer and then installed WIndows from the computer,not inserting the cd. I dont have the cd,i have the backup of the whole cd.

Comment: @shovon Of course, you can reinstall Windows at any time later. Yes, plug out the cable. If you have a valid license key, you can get a Windows ISO (search on Google) to do a clean install.